# In Android 4.2, when programmatically installing an APK using an intent, how do you allow downgrades?

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, apk, android-4.2-jelly-bean

As of 4.2, using the following code to install an APK, the install fails if the APK version is lower than the currently installed version.  Is there a PutExtra() that will allow the downgrade?

```
File file = new File(dir, "App.apk");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Or do I need to do it a different way?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to support downgrades in general, except by uninstalling the app, or installing via **`adb`** (for developers).

Comment: I never managed to downgrade an installed app even with adb :-/ The only solution I know of is uninstalling the app first. It is also very reasonable because private settings and persistent data layouts may change from version to version. An older version of an app is unlikely to cope with data changes in newer versions.

Comment: when using pm from the command line in 4.2 there is a -d option to allow downgrades.  I want to do the same thing when launching the install from my application

Comment: If this has upset your enterprise customers as much as it has mine, star the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62545

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the allowing downgrades is the function of application is being install if this app allows to be downgraded the it will downgrade the currently installed app otherwise you can't

so from your **Intent** you can not control it

The setting you can set in your application

This property you can set in your manifest

[image: This property]

Comment: I am using Mono for android, so the "Restore needs application" option does not exist in the IDE. But adding android:restoreAnyVersion="true" to the <application> section in the androidmanifest.xml did not resolve the issue in Android 4.2.  Is there other options I need in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

At least with same versionname / versioncode works following extra to the intent 
(for me (Android 4.2.2, Galaxy S4 Active):

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH_TO_FILE_APK));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra('Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED', "your.package.name");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

In my case, this restarts the app after replacing.